# JAVA: Stream any file to browser correctly

Tags: java, file, stream, server

So I have created my own personal HTTP Server in Java from scratch.
So far it is working fine but with one major flaw.
When I try to pass **big files** to the browser I get a **Java Heap Space error**. I know how to fix this error through the JVM but I am looking for the long term solution for this.

```
//declare an integer for the byte length of the file
int length = (int) f.length();

//start the fileinput stream.
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

//byte array with the length of the file
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

//write the file until the bytes is empty.

while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) != -1 ){
    write(bytes, 0, length);
}
flush();

//close the file input stream
fis.close();
```

This way sends the file to the browser **successfully** and **streams it perfectly** but the issue is, because I am creating a byte array with the length of the file. When the file is very big I get the Heap Space error.

I have **eliminated** this issue by using a buffer as shown below and I dont get Heap Space errors anymore. **BUT** the way shown below does not stream the files in the browser correctly. It's as if the file bytes are being shuffled and are being sent to the browser all together.

```
final int bufferSize = 4096;
byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

FileInputStream     fis = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

  while ( true )
  {
     int length = bis.read( buffer, 0, bufferSize );
     if ( length < 0 ) break;
     write( buffer, 0, length );
  }
 flush();
 bis.close();
 fis.close();
```

**NOTE1:**

**All** the correct **Response Headers** are being sent perfectly to the browser.

**Note2:**

**Both** ways work **perfectly** on a **computer** browser but only the **first** way works on a **smartphone's browser** (but sometimes it gives me **Heap Space error**).
If someone knows how to correctly send files to a browser and stream them correctly I would be a very very happy man.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You don't appear to be sending a `Content-Length` header, and I don't see a `Content-Type` either. The headers are fairly important to HTTP.

Comment: oh I forgot to add that to my question. Response Headers are being sent correctly!

Comment: Are you using Apache commons? If so, then you could try `IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);`.

Comment: I can quibble with the style of your code and some of the details, but the browser's point of view, the second version should behave identically to the first. Be more specific about what you mean by, "It's as if the file bytes are being shuffled and are being sent to the browser all together." That's not helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: @erickson yeah this is exactly what I thought too. but when I play an mp3, or mp4 video file through a phones browser, android tv, ipad etc. the files are being streamed weirdly.

Comment: "Weirdly" means what, exactly?

Comment: @nickb no, I am not using Apache commons.It's all pure Java no external libraries whatsoever

Comment: What's the `write()` method you are using to write the data? Perhaps the bug is there, and it only shows up when called repeatedly.

Comment: it's as if the bytes are being played in different order. I don't know how to put it in words. Lets say you are listening to bohemian rhapsody it would play like: just  Mama, just man killed head a against a gun his Put but not that harmonic. Don't make fun of me haha at least I tried to explain it :)

Comment: I am not sure you trying to achieve but as a test you could use java.io.RandomAccessFile on the client and server not to read the whole file at a time but sequence of <=30MB blocks or something to avoid the annoying outofmemory errors for example; An example can be found here https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/randomaccessfile/java-randomaccessfile-example/

Comment: @erickson DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));

Comment: @erickson this is what I use and in code it is: out.write() I just removed out to make it look more clean

Comment: Okay, what other details have you left out?

Comment: @erickson I haven't left anything else out to be honest

Comment: You shouldn't read the entire file into a buffer for streaming, with buffering you should be reading and writing one byte at a time (and let the buffer handle it).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading from a `BufferedInputStream` you can allow its' buffer to handle the buffering, there is no reason to read everything into a `byte[]` (and certainly not a `byte[]` of the entire File). Read one `byte` at a time, and rely on the internal buffer of the stream. Something like,

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
int abyte;
while ((abyte = bis.read()) != -1 ){
    write(abyte);
}
```

Comment: this actually makes it work Elliott, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Emm... As I can see it, you try to use chunks in your code anyway,
as I can remember,  even the apache [HttpClient+FileUpload](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload) solution has file size limit about <=2.1GB or something *(correct me if I am wrong)* so it is a bit hard thing...

I haven't tried the solution yet but as a test you can use [java.io.RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) in combination with File(Input/Output)Stream on the client and server not to read and write the whole file at a time but sequence of lets say <=30MB blocks for example to avoid the annoying outofmemory errors ; An example of using RandomAccessFile can be found here https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/randomaccessfile/java-randomaccessfile-example/

But still you give less details :( I mean is your client suppose to be a common Java application or not?

---

If you have some additional information please let me know

Good luck :)